# Check if data is new to user since users last visit

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on an web app where users can upload book titles as many as they want. Other users can see all these uploaded book titles from all the users who have contributed with uploads.

The above is done by a simple while loop and just printing all the information from my book title table.

Here's a simple snippet of the above which is working successfully:

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($titles)) {

   $title = $row['title'];
   echo $title;
   }
```

My question is this; I'm trying to figure out how and if is it possible to make a function so when a user visits the page he can see all the new uploaded book titles since his last visit.

Example using glowing color to show new titles:

The page starts with 5 book titles.

User 1 visit page and views all 5 uploaded titles.

User 1 leaves page.

User 2 uploads two new titles.

User 1 visits the page again, and the two new titles from user 2 are shown with a glowing color. He leaves the page.

user 3 visits the page for the very first time; all 7 titles are glowing, they are all new to him.

user 1 visits the page again, this time none of them are glowing as he has already seen them before.

Is above possible with PHP? I haven't been able to view any SO posts regarding my problem, as I have a hard time expressing what this related problem is called and therefor haven't been able to search on it. If anyone knows of an existing post, I would appreciate getting a link to it.

Comment: You can try setting a cookie (or any other stored value) for each user, containing his last visit timestamp. All titles uploaded after this timestamp are marked as new. Timestamp updates when user starts a new session.

Comment: Worth noting that you would also need to record timestamps for each title entry as well.

Comment: @Noobus I see, that makes very much sense. I'll do it this way. Thank you

Comment: @RussJ That is hereby noted! Thank you.

Comment: @Noobus I tried using sessions, but then I'm facing a problem when my user logouts. On the logout I destroy the sessions.. so then my site wont remember the last time the user visited my website?

Comment: If you can authorize users, you can store last visit time on your server, in a separate table or simply in the auth table itself. It would be even better.